# Jackson 2 Json deserialization working only with explicit Mapper

Tags: json, weblogic, fasterxml, jackson2, jackson-databind

I'm struggling with automatic jackson json deserialization. My requirement is that json with all lowercase property name (or completly different to bean property name) is correctly deserialized (bean properties with camel case notation).

Application Server: Weblogic 12.2.1

Sample json which should work:

```
{"firstname":"Max","lastname":"Mustermann"}
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Bean

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastname")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig (autogenerated from Netbeans)

```
@ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(at.eurotours.exportService.jaxrs.resource.PersonResource.class);
    }
}
```

Resource

```
@Path("person")
public class PersonResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/person1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getPerson1(String requestBody) throws IOException   {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(requestBody, Person.class);
        return Response.ok((String) person.getFirstName()).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/person2")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getPerson2(Person person) {
        return Response.ok((String) person.getFirstName()).build();
    }
}
```

First variant of **getPerson1(String requestBody)** is working but second one with **getPerson2(Person person)** not. Parameter variable **person** is not null but fields **firstName**/**lastName** are both null.

**requestBody** content:

```
{"firstname":"Max","lastname":"Mustermann"}
```

After trying for nearly one day (and searching "whole" internet) I'm completly stuck and don't know what the reason could be.

Comment: Are you sure your application container is using Jackson for JSON binding? What product are you using? Did you configure anything about that? Because if it is not, it won't care about Jackson-specific annotations.

Comment: Can you try to print out the value of requestBody? I think there could be a casing-issue (firstName vs firstname, etc.)

Comment: Added information about application server (Weblogic 12c) and output of requestBody.

Comment: WebLogic maybe uses MOXy instead of Jackson: https://dzone.com/articles/oracle-weblogic-1212-now You should use the standard `@XmlAttribute` annotation instead (which I believe Jackson also honours)

Comment: why don't you use JAXB ? you don't need any external library jersey will take care of JSON serialization and de-serialization